# SQL Server Recursive CTE not returning expected rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursion

I'm building a Markov chain name generator. I'm trying to replace a `while` loop with a recursive CTE. Limitations in using `top` and `order by` in the recursive part of the CTE have led me down the following path.

The point of all of this is to generate names, based on a model, which is just another word that I've chunked out into three character segments, stored in three columns in the `Markov_Model` table. The next character in the sequence will be a character from the `Markov_Model`, such that the 1st and 2nd characters in the model match the penultimate and ultimate character in the word being generated. Rather than generate a probability matrix for the that third character, I'm using a scalar function that finds all the characters that fit the criteria, and gets one of them randomly: `order by newid()`.

The problem is that this formulation of the CTE gets the desired number of rows in the anchor segment, but the union that recursively calls the CTE only `union`s one row from the anchor. I've attached a sample of the desired output at the bottom.

The query:

```
;with names as 
(
    select top 5
        cast('+' as nvarchar(50)) as char1,
        cast('+' as nvarchar(50)) as char2,
        cast(char3 as nvarchar(50)) as char3,
        cast('++' + char3 as nvarchar(100)) as name_in_progress,
        1 as iteration
    from markov_Model
    where char1 is null
        and char2 is null
    order by newid()                 -- Get some random starting characters

    union all

    select
        n.char2 as char1,
        n.char3 as char2,
        cast(fnc.addition as nvarchar(50)) as char3,
        cast(n.name_in_progress + fnc.addition as nvarchar(100)),
        1 + n.iteration 
    from names n
    cross apply (
        -- This function takes the preceding two characters, 
        -- and gets a random character that follows the pattern
        select isnull(dbo.[fn_markov_getNext] (n.char2, n.char3), ',') as addition
    ) fnc
)
select * 
from names
option (maxrecursion 3)          -- For debug
```

The trouble is the `union` only `union`s one row.

Example output:

```
char1   char2   char3   name_in_progress    iteration
+       +       F       ++F                 1
+       +       N       ++N                 1
+       +       K       ++K                 1
+       +       S       ++S                 1
+       +       B       ++B                 1
+       B       a       ++Ba                2
B       a       c       ++Bac               3
a       c       h       ++Bach              4
```

Note I'm using `+` and `,` as `null` replacers/delimeters.

What I want to see is the entirety of the previous recursion, with the addition of the new characters to the `name_in_progress`; each pass should modify the entirely of the previous pass.

My desired output would be:

[image]

Top 10 of the `Markov_Model` table:

[image]

Text of the function that gets the next character from the `Markov_Model`:

```
CREATEFUNCTION [dbo].[fn_markov_getNext]
(
    @char2 nvarchar(1),
    @char3 nvarchar(1)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(1)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @newChar nvarchar(1)

    set @newChar = (
        select top 1
            isnull(char3, ',')
        from markov_Model mm 
        where isnull(mm.char1, '+') = isnull(@char2, '+')
            and isnull(mm.char2, '+') = isnull(@char3, ',')
        order by (select new_id from vw_getGuid)    -- A view that calls newid()
    )

    return @newChar

END
```

Comment: what's the expected results for the given name_in_progress?

Comment: What is "a random character that follows the pattern"? That sounds like an oxymoron to me. I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: What happens if you change `maxrecursion` to 15?

Comment: Not clear to me what the problem is.

Comment: Can you post the contents of the `Markov_Model` table and the definition of the `fn_markov_getNext` function?